# Add Class in html Dynamically in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to add class in anchor tag dynamically by using Java script or Jquery. I have find many solution but not what i am looking. I am want to use PHP dynamic header and footer. for that i want to add "active" class in current page that i or user will use.

Please help me out.

Thank in advance.

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li>
        <a href="index.php"><i class="icon-home"></i><br />Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="icon-camera"></i><br />Portfolio</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: See [JQuery addclass to selected div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877544/jquery-addclass-to-selected-div-remove-class-if-another-div-is-selected)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$thisPage = "home";

?>
<html>
<head>
 ...
 ...
<body>
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<li <?php if($thisPage == "home") echo 'class="active"'; ?>>
    <a href="index.php"><i class="icon-home"></i><br />Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="icon-camera"></i><br />Portfolio</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something lie this

```
<?php 

$urlArr = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$active_class = array_pop($urlArr); ?>


<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="<?php echo ($active_class == "index.php") ? "active" : ""; ?>">
        <a href="index.php"><i class="icon-home"></i><br />Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($active_class == "portfolio.html") ? "active" : ""; ?>">
        <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="icon-camera"></i><br />Portfolio</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want client-side to handle such things, following snippet should give you the idea how to do it. And you should notice that your URL of **index.php** should have been shown in the URL. As it's mostly overridden by htaccess.

Following example is about visiting an URL of `http://example.org/portfolio.html`

```
//First, get the current URL
var url = window.location.href;  //output: http://example.org/portfolio.html

//Then split them to array by '/'
var arrurl = url.split('/');  //output: Array [ "http:", "", "example.org", "portfolio.html" ]

//Get last portion of the uri
var lasturi = arrurl[arrurl.length-1];  //output: portfolio.html

//Split the last segment by '.'
var arruri = lasturi.split('.');  //output: Array [ "portfolio", "html" ]

//Get the first value of previous array
var page = arruri[0];  //output: portfolio
```

Now, iterate to the navbar. I put an ID to it for better selector. `<ul id="mynavbar" class="nav pull-right">`

```
//Iterate to navbar
$('#mynavbar a').each(function () {
    //Get attribute href value
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    //Split by '.' to array
    var arrhref = href.split('.');

    //Get the first portion
    var hrefportion = arrhref[0];

    //Now, we should add class 'active' to the href (also parent li element)
    //if the 'hrefportion' is equal to 'page' in this case 'portfolio'
    if (hrefportion == page) {
        //Add 'active class to the anchor
        $(this).addClass("active");

        //also its parent li element
        var li = $(this).parent();
        li.addClass("active");
    }
});
```