# addclass not successfully implementing

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slash-menu nav').click(function(){
       $('.slash-menu nav').addClass('active');
  });
```

});

After the Jquery is executed this →

```
<nav class="slash-menu"></nav>
```

should become this →

```
<nav class="slash-menu active"></nav>
```

But this is not happening.

[Source of my Learning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877544/jquery-addclass-to-selected-div-remove-class-if-another-div-is-selected)

Comment: Easiest way to debug selectors is to go in the browser console and enter `$(selector).length` if it's zero, your selector is wrong.  eg `$('.slash-menu nav').length` vs `$('.slash-menu').length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. selector is wrong. `.slash-menu nav` means element with class `slash-menu` find child nav. based on html mark up should be element nav with class `slash-menu`
2. use this context

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav.slash-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="slash-menu">red</nav>
<nav >not red</nav>
```

Comment: [Link](https://www.screencast.com/t/JyVX4ftYF) I did as you suggested, but sill not working. ]

Comment: @AdiYogi which bar?

Comment: you class is `header-menu"` please check not `slash-menu` in the nav @AdiYogi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149561/discussion-between-adiyogi-and-guradio).

Comment: ahh I got the error I think its div not nav. let me try with that.

Comment: but on clicking again it doesn't go back to the previous. means on clicking again it doesn't remove that class.

Comment: @AdiYogi use `.toggleClass()` instead of `.addClass()`

Comment: It worked, great learning for me today. Please upvote  me too.

Comment: glad to help mate

Answer (score 2):

it's because your selector is looking for a `<nav>` element inside `.slash-menu` - target like this:

```
$('nav.slash-menu').click(function()
{
    $(this).addClass('active')
})
```

Comment: [Link](https://www.screencast.com/t/JyVX4ftYF) I did as you suggested, but sill not working. ]

Comment: @AdiYogi - interesting, it should work. Use .length on `$('nav.slash-menu')` to see if it returns bigger than 0